# How nested if-else work without curly braces?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int aNumber = 3;
        if (aNumber >= 0)
            if (aNumber == 0)
                System.out.println("first string");
        else 
            System.out.println("second string");
        System.out.println("third string");

    }
}
```

outputs

```
second string
third string
```

where I expects

```
third string
```

because the else of `System.out.println("second string");` should be for `if (aNumber == 0)`.
My questions are

- Is it required to write all the inner `if`'s `else` before writing the outer `else`
- Is it allowed to write statements between `if`-`else` statements of outer `if`

  ```
  if(condition) {
      if(anotherCondition) {
          someCode();
      }
      //execute code here
  } else {
      anotherCode();
  }
  ```

Comment: "should be for if (aNumber >= 0)" that is correct, and in your example, aNumber = 3, which meets this condition. Where is the problem?

Comment: I meant == not >= edited